# html form input slider / range with non numeric values?

Tags: jquery, html, input, range

```
<input type="range" min="2" max="52" value="4" step="1"/>
```

Can I have one of these input ranges with non-numeric intervals? Like "Yes" then "maybe" then "no"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `range` of html `input` is [designed for imprecise input values](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.range.html).

Anyway, if you really want to use a slider for this purpose, you can maybe set on your script that 0 is no, 1 is maybe and 2 is yes. In jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
$("#slider").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "0":
          /* change a text/hidden value to 'no' */
          break;
        case "1":
          /* change a text/hidden value to 'maybe' */
          break;
        case "2":
          /* change a text/hidden value to 'yes' */
          break;
      }
}).change();
```

Live example:
http://jsbin.com/upeyew